# How to connect wifi adapter tp-link tl-wn722nc with raspberry pi model b?

Tags: raspbian, wifi

How to get up to work wifi adapter tp-link tl-wn722nc with raspberry pi model b?
Do i need to install some drivers?
Does the tp-link tl-wn722nc work on raspberry pi model b ?
How the all process is going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a driver to install, but in order to find which one, you need to identify the chipset in your specific dongle.

1. Boot up your Pi, without connecting your WiFi adapter
2. Open a terminal (CTRL-ALT-T)
3. Enter command `lsusb`
4. Connect your WiFi adapter
5. Enter command `lsusb` again, and compare the list of devices to your previous list from step 3. The new entry is your WiFi adapter, listing the chipset.
6. Follow [these](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi) instructions.

Comment: after i install the driver what's next?

Comment: There's a few steps in the instructions (click on the ink in step 6) to make sure the Pi has everything it needs to use WiFi, after that, you should be able to use WiFi.

Comment: so how to use wifi?

Comment: [How To Use WiFi](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse)